# Issue with Mathematica Interface Colors in Linux

Tags: configuration

I have Mathematica installed on Linux and I have noticed that the colors are quite difficult to read. I am not sure how to configure the colors Mathematica uses for its interface components. In the following images, you can see how the colors in the banner and text are hard to read. This includes Find/Replace dialogs and other elements.

My question is this: where does Mathematica draw these colors from?

[image: Colors in Banner are Hard to Read]

[image: Colors when Opening Files are Also Hard to Read]

EDIT: I just dug in a bit and realized that Mathematica draws its colors from QT, so this question has been answered.

Comment: If you have an adequate answer, why don't you post it as answer? It is not uncommon to answer your own question.

Comment: What halirutan said. Writing a proper answer, possibly with relevant details, is much more helpful to others than "[Answered by Submitter]" in the title.